# Code to execute upon Application exit

Tags: c#, ms-word

I'm working on creating a Microsoft Word addin that will integrate with our EDRMS system.
I want to be able to execute a bit of code when Word is being shutdown.

The code will pick the name of the Document that is being closed down and delete it from the User's local path.

The bit of code that Checks In the document, Saves it and then deletes if from the Local Path work perfectly if I put it within a Test button.

Im just having problem figuring out where I would place that bit of code so that it executes when Word is being shutdown.

I have tried put it in the Startup code of the Addin.

`Document vstoDoc = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(this.Application.ActiveDocument);` as shown below throws an error message as when the addin loads there is no Active Document.

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{

    private InfoInsertTask myUserControl1;
    private Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane myCustomTaskPane;

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        myUserControl1 = new InfoInsertTask();
        myCustomTaskPane = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(myUserControl1, "");

        DocumentDeactivate();
    }
    private void DocumentDeactivate()
    {
        Document vstoDoc = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(this.Application.ActiveDocument);
        vstoDoc.Deactivate += new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.WindowEventHandler(ThisDocument_Deactivate);
    }

    void ThisDocument_Deactivate(object sender, Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.WindowEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("The document has been deactivated");
    }

    private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check whether your word document has closed or not. Not the whole application.
If you are using a word document in your custom task pane, there are multiple events for you to handle. 
Quote from MSDN

> Word Events
>   To monitor the state of document windows in Word, you can handle the following events:
>
> E:Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationEvents4_Event.DocumentBeforeClose
>   E:Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationEvents4_Event.DocumentOpen
>   E:Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationEvents4_Event.NewDocument
>   E:Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationEvents4_Event.WindowActivate
>   E:Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationEvents4_Event.WindowDeactivate

Please read this article from MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942864.aspx